# bash shell while loop is going beyond the conditional expression

Tags: bash, shell-script

In my problem, it appears like `j` value and `i` value reach `6`; where `i` should only run up to `5`. Can someone please explain ?

```
i=0;
j=0;
echo "values of $i and $j" > debug.txt;
while [ $j -le 5 ]
do
    j=expr $j + 1
    i=expr $i + 1
    echo "values of $i and $j" >> debug.txt
done;
cat debug.txt;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
value of i is  0 and j is  0
value of i is  1 and j is  1
value of i is  2 and j is  2
value of i is  3 and j is  3
value of i is  4 and j is  4
value of i is  5 and j is  5
value of i is  6 and j is  6
```

Comment: Downvoted, this is a simple logic error, and should have been noticed by the coder. Simple debugging, dude.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your script isn't working is because you are using `-le`. This causes your script to think that when it reaches 5, it will still execute because it is equal to 5. Change the `-le` to `-lt`.

Comment: Dude, anyway it should not go beyond 5 right ...

Comment: @SaiKoti Listen to the logic here, 5 is less than or equal to 5, execute again. The number increments to 6, and the script stops because 6 is not less than or equal to 5.

Comment: let me try in another way buddy

Comment: @SaiKoti What the hell are you talking about!? If you ABSOLUTELY need to use `-le`, use `[ $j -le 4 ]`.

Comment: So, Previously what i thought that ...during the execution of while loop, if the value exceeds 5 in the body then it will come out of that loop immediately. Now i got that, only when entering that loop, it will check for the value. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @SaiKoti Sorry about my harshness, I just found it insane that that this wasn't obvious to you.